# Laravel 4 eloquent query to combine data from single table

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to make a tv schedule where the current and next upcoming show is displayed of each channel.
I want to do something like this:

```
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Now Playing</th>
                        <th>Next Upcoming Show</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                @foreach ($shows as $show)
                    <tr>
                    <td>
                        <strong>{{ $show->channel->name}}</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>{{ date('H:i', strtotime($show->now->start)) }}</strong>
                       {{ $show->now->title }}</td>
                    <td><strong>{{ date('H:i', strtotime($show->next->start)) }}</strong>
                       {{ $show->next->title }}</td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach        
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

I get the now playing show like this: 
        $shows = Show::with('channel')
                ->where('start', '<=', DB::raw('(NOW() - INTERVAL 15 SECOND)'))
                ->where('end', '>', DB::raw('(NOW() + INTERVAL 15 SECOND)'))
                ->orderBy('start')->get();

I can't seem to get the next upcoming show of each channel in the same query.
it would be cool if i could something like this for the current show: $show->now->start and for the next show: $show->next->start

any ideas?

My db:

```
    Schema::create('channels', function(Blueprint $table) {     
         $table->increments('id');
         $table->string('name', 200);
         $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('shows', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('channel_id');
        $table->string('title', 255);
        $table->text('description')->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('start');
        $table->dateTime('end');
    });
```

Comment: More info about your database structure, or even the raw query you're trying to produce, would surely help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it would be easier to do it the other way around? Loop it by the channels and do `$channel->next->...` and `$channel->now->...`

In your `Channel` model you could do something like:

```
public function next()
{
    // Change this for your "get next" query
    return $this->hasOne('Show')->where('start', '<=', DB::raw('(NOW() - INTERVAL 15 SECOND)')) ->where('end', '>', DB::raw('(NOW() + INTERVAL 15 SECOND)')) ->orderBy('start');
}

public function now()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Show')->where('start', '<=', DB::raw('(NOW() - INTERVAL 15 SECOND)')) ->where('end', '>', DB::raw('(NOW() + INTERVAL 15 SECOND)')) ->orderBy('start');
}
```

Then do:

```
$channels = Channel::with(array('next', 'now'))->get();
```

and

```
@foreach($channels as $channel)
    Now: {{ $channel->now->title }} <br>
    Next: {{ $channel->next->title }}
@endforeach
```

I didn't test this at all, it's just a thought/suggestion.

Comment: Wow Jesper! that workes like a charm! didn't knew you could do that in the Model! Thanks for ur help!